# Find integration limit given the value of the (2D) integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, gaussian-integral

(Previously asked on Stackoverflow - now deleted - it was pointed out that it makes more sense to ask my question here.)

I am trying to solve for R_j(I_0) given in Eq. 12 of [this paper](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1996ApJ...468..369I) (see also Eq. 10; both screenshots below) given that we know the LHS; that is, given the LHS, I'd like to find the integration limit of one of the (two) integrals.

[image: Eq. 12]
[image: Eq. 10]

Currently, on Python, I am iterating through every value of R_j (i.e., j taking on a value from 0 to N) and finding the value of R_j such that the difference between the LHS and the evaluated integral is minimized. A code snippet is below. However, this is prohibitively slow (with 1600 points, this takes >3000 hours!). Is there a more efficient way of calculating the integration limit?

```
import numpy as np 
import mpmath as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(len(R_j))): #for every frequency value
    pdf = lambda r,s: 1/(2*S_j*S_j_err[i]*mp.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * s * mp.exp( -(s-S_j[i])**2/(2*S_j_err[i]**2) - r*s/S_j[i] )
    probs = np.array([ mp.quad(pdf,[R_j[j],mp.inf],[0,mp.inf]) for j in tqdm(range(len(R_j))) ])
```

Comment: One reason it's slow is because quad is slow (to guarantee accuracy). However your integrand decay pretty quickly so integrating over a finite interval and using np.trapz could work well and would be much faster. The only downside is that you are yourself now responsible for ensuring that its accurate enough.

Comment: Another thing that makes it slow is your choice of algorithm. You can use a better root-finding algorithm than simply looping over *all* values. Bisection or Newton's method are usually better choices.

Comment: I think that you need to evaluate $f_{R_j(I_0)}(r)$ once, store it as a grid function. Then evaluate $F(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} f(r) dr$. Note that $F(x)$ should not be computed as $N$ separate quadratures, but using ODE solver instead. Do you really need multiprecision here? It is probably very slow

Comment: Oh, I see that $f_{R_j(I_0)}(r)$ depends also on $S_j(I_0)$ and $\sigma_{S_j(I_0)}$ which seem to be different for different $R_j(I_0)$. Anyway, the function can be evaluated to an explicit expression via $\operatorname{erf}$ function